# Is there any way to restrict access to web resources without using web.xml in a Java web app?

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets

I want to give access to some of the resources in my web application to the logged-in users only. I implemented the authentication without using any j_security_check as I find it very rigid and non-transparent. I want to know if there is any clean way of restricting access to the web resources without being dependent on the web.xml(security-constraint and web-resource-collection elements).

Also, I do not want to use any bloated frameworks such as Spring or such.

Comment: You can always put your resources inside your `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Let us say a user has already logged in. Now he enters the direct URL to a JSP, then I would need to show the page without restricting the access. If I keep it in WEB-INF then it is not possible to this easily.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without more specifics.  For instance, you don't say how you implemented authentication, what sort of authentication details your mechanism has captured, or where it has put them.

Comment: I just wrote a servlet which checks the hash of the password and the user id against a table in db and if it passes then it sets a User (roles and profile information) object in the session to be used by the rest of web app. That is all i did as of now. Now I am kind of stuck with restricting access like the way web.xml does it. I am thinking of writing some filters to accomplish this but I am not sure.

Comment: who told you spring is bloated?

Comment: @Bozho have a look at the relative size of the frameworks here http://www.web4j.com/Java_Web_Application_Framework_Overview.jsp ...I do not mean anything negative about Spring..i am just saying it is a heavy framework with lots of classes. I did use it for last 3 years or so.

Comment: @Narendra - if you equate codebase size to bloat, then Java 7 has to be a massive case of bloat compared to Java 1.1.  Yet everyone and his dog is prepared to complain about what it is missing from Java.  And nobody likes coding using the totally unbloated Java ME.  *(WARNING: this comment has been exaggerated for dramatic effect.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `Filter`, map it to `/*` and let it handle the restricted resources. List them in your own configuration file, and check if a user is logged when accessing one of these resources. If not - redirect to a login page; if yes - continue (`chain.doFilter(..)`)

Comment: Or even if it doesn't, the next guy who looks at his code will proclaim it to be bloated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the security model controlled by web.xml is the primary way of controlling authorisation. I think you're in danger of re-inventing the wheel here. The standard facilities are really quite powerful, I'd agree that there's a learning curve but resources such as [these](http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security) help.

For dynamic resources you are free to implement your own authorisation model, and for complex authorisation that is what folks do, [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/fine-grained-web-authorization) may help.